# implicit intent for contact groups list

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-implicit-intent

I want to pick group (Contact Group).
I found code to open Contacts Activity but didn't found for Group.

```
Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intentContact);
```

Is there anyone know how to open following activity implicitly?

[image]

I have done googling but no found more solution.

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

Pratik

Comment: I am also looking for the same but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this .

Comment: You should comment this :)